# How to properly use `install` command line command in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, installation

I have a makefile which installs a lot of files in my target build directory. Some of these are executable, some are not.

I tested the `install` command with flags `-D -m 644` for non-executable files earlier with Linux, but now it broke. I have discovered that `-D` flag is not available with OSX/BSD, and have removed it. The thing is, I need to make sure that the component directories in the paths of files I am installing are created as necessary. I thought the `-d` flag will help and tried things along the lines of:

```
install .DS_Store ./tmp/build/some_dir/
```

...but it complains that `some_dir` is "no such file or directory", i.e. it does not exist (which is true). I then tried the same as above but with the `-d` flag, and got another error:

> install: .DS_Store exists but is not a directory

I just want a more or less stable and generic way to copy files to destination. Maybe I should resort to `cp`? I know the minor but important differences between the two, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`install -d` interprets all of its arguments as directories that (might) need to be created. Thus, I think you need to do it as two commands:

```
install -d ./tmp/build/some_dir/
install .DS_Store ./tmp/build/some_dir/
```